# Dynamically Resize Complex Canvas Path HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I've created a drawing of a truck using paths in an HTML5 canvas. The canvas image itself is close to 900 lines of code and I've implemented a function to draw the image based on a resize ratio determined by the window's width/height. The end result is that the canvas and all elements within the canvas are dynamically resized to fit the contents of the window.

Keep in mind that I'm only on day 2 of utilizing the canvas, so I may have missed something, but there has got to be an easier way to accomplish what I am doing. So, my question is: **Is there an easier way / method to accomplish resizing the canvas and its internal elements when complex paths are involved?**

A sample of my code is below and only resizes on body load, I've not attached it to an onresize listener yet... I could not fit it all in so you can get the full source here:

http://www.epixseo.com/fullsource.txt

as you can see, I pass the canvasWidth into the semitruckv1 function and determine a resize ratio.... then multiply every coordinate and lineWidth with that resize ratio... which takes a while to do... (you should be able to copy+paste the full source code and run local in your IDE)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Semi truck</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  body {
      margin:0px;
  }
  </style>
  <script>

    function init() {

        var viewportWidth = window.innerWidth;
        var viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;

        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

        var canvasWidth = viewportWidth;
        var canvasHeight = viewportHeight;
        canvas.style.position = "fixed";
        canvas.setAttribute("width", canvasWidth);
        canvas.setAttribute("height", canvasHeight);

        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        semitruckv1(ctx, canvasWidth);
    }

    function semitruckv1(ctx, canvasWidth) {
        //347 default width of initial image

        var resizeRatio = canvasWidth/347;
      // semitruckv1/Path
      ctx.save();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(251.3*resizeRatio, 143.8*resizeRatio);
      ctx.bezierCurveTo(251.3*resizeRatio, 146.9*resizeRatio, 253.9*resizeRatio, 149.5*resizeRatio, 257.0*resizeRatio, 149.5*resizeRatio);
      ctx.bezierCurveTo(260.2*resizeRatio, 149.5*resizeRatio, 262.8*resizeRatio, 146.9*resizeRatio, 262.8*resizeRatio, 143.8*resizeRatio);
      ctx.bezierCurveTo(262.8*resizeRatio, 140.6*resizeRatio, 260.2*resizeRatio, 138.1*resizeRatio, 257.0*resizeRatio, 138.1*resizeRatio);
      ctx.bezierCurveTo(253.9*resizeRatio, 138.1*resizeRatio, 251.3*resizeRatio, 140.6*resizeRatio, 251.3*resizeRatio, 143.8*resizeRatio);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(1, 1, 1)";
      ctx.lineWidth = 1*resizeRatio;
      ctx.stroke();

      // semitruckv1/Path
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(243.3*resizeRatio, 143.8*resizeRatio);
      ctx.bezierCurveTo(243.3*resizeRatio, 151.4*resizeRatio, 249.5*resizeRatio, 157.5*resizeRatio, 257.0*resizeRatio, 157.5*resizeRatio);
      ctx.bezierCurveTo(264.6*resizeRatio, 157.5*resizeRatio, 270.8*resizeRatio, 151.4*resizeRatio, 270.8*resizeRatio, 143.8*resizeRatio);
      ctx.bezierCurveTo(270.8*resizeRatio, 136.2*resizeRatio, 264.6*resizeRatio, 130.1*resizeRatio, 257.0*resizeRatio, 130.1*resizeRatio);
      ctx.bezierCurveTo(249.5*resizeRatio, 130.1*resizeRatio, 243.3*resizeRatio, 136.2*resizeRatio, 243.3*resizeRatio, 143.8*resizeRatio);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.lineWidth = 1*resizeRatio;
      ctx.stroke();

      // semitruckv1/Path
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(241.3*resizeRatio, 143.8*resizeRatio);
      ctx.bezierCurveTo(241.3*resizeRatio, 152.5*resizeRatio, 248.3*resizeRatio, 159.6*resizeRatio, 257.0*resizeRatio, 159.6*resizeRatio);
      ctx.bezierCurveTo(265.7*resizeRatio, 159.6*resizeRatio, 272.8*resizeRatio, 152.5*resizeRatio, 272.8*resizeRatio, 143.8*resizeRatio);
      ctx.bezierCurveTo(272.8*resizeRatio, 135.1*resizeRatio, 265.7*resizeRatio, 128.0*resizeRatio, 257.0*resizeRatio, 128.0*resizeRatio);
      ctx.bezierCurveTo(248.3*resizeRatio, 128.0*resizeRatio, 241.3*resizeRatio, 135.1*resizeRatio, 241.3*resizeRatio, 143.8*resizeRatio);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.lineWidth = 0.3*resizeRatio;
      ctx.stroke();

      // semitruckv1/Path
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(232.5*resizeRatio, 143.8*resizeRatio);
      ctx.bezierCurveTo(232.5*resizeRatio, 157.3*resizeRatio, 243.5*resizeRatio, 168.3*resizeRatio, 257.0*resizeRatio, 168.3*resizeRatio);
      ctx.bezierCurveTo(270.6*resizeRatio, 168.3*resizeRatio, 281.6*resizeRatio, 157.3*resizeRatio, 281.6*resizeRatio, 143.8*resizeRatio);
      ctx.bezierCurveTo(281.6*resizeRatio, 130.2*resizeRatio, 270.6*resizeRatio, 119.3*resizeRatio, 257.0*resizeRatio, 119.3*resizeRatio);
      ctx.bezierCurveTo(243.5*resizeRatio, 119.3*resizeRatio, 232.5*resizeRatio, 130.2*resizeRatio, 232.5*resizeRatio, 143.8*resizeRatio);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.lineWidth = 0.5*resizeRatio;
      ctx.stroke();

      //THERE ARE ABOUT ANOTHER 800 LINES OF PATH DRAWING DOWNLOAD THE FULL SOURCE TO VIEW: www.epixseo.com/fullsource.txt

    }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body onLoad="init()">
   <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A canvas context has a `scale` function, which will automatically scale anything drawn on the canvas until the context has been restored, or you change the scale back to 1. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Transformations#A_scale_example

Comment: +1 for the tutorial, I saw scale before, but after reading that tutorial, scale appears to be the direction i should head in, ill give it a shot tomorrow and if it is what i need you got the answer, thanks for taking the time

Comment: I was able to use scale to achieve the result I was looking for, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about using canvas (I have GameMaker:HTML5 do it for me), but can't you just load an SVG image and draw it at the appropriate size?

Comment: This is being deployed as a mobile app and and unfortunately android and SVG don't get along quite yet, otherwise I would love to use SVG, but cannot in this instance so I had to resort to canvas

Answer (score 0):

the best way to handle this depends on your future applications for example:

1. If you are just drawing the same truck but want to redraw when the page is resized instead use [toDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement) method of the canvas to pull the image of the canvas then resize the canvas (using .width and .height instead of css because you will stretch the image) then use the [drawImage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images) method to draw that data url back to the canvas (or just plop it into an img tag).
2. If you plan to animate a piece of the truck, the wheels for example, you should use the same strategy as step one however instead of pulling an image of the truck pull only pieces. For example if you are animating the wheels: Pull an image of the main body of the truck then pull an image of just a wheel, then draw the truck once at resize, but then continuously redraw the wheels rotating them slightly every frame.